# Load state of UISwitch from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch

I have managed to change the state of my `UISwitch` and save to `NSUserDefaults`.

My `UISwitch` is in a different view from the main view and when I flip between views, my `UISwitch` button always appears ON even though the state may be OFF.

```
- (IBAction)truthonoff:(id)sender {
    if(_truthonoff.on) {
        // lights on

        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setValue:@"yes" forKey:@"truthonoff"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        self.status.text = @"on";
    }

    else {
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [defaults setValue:@"no" forKey:@"truthonoff"];
        [defaults synchronize];

        self.status.text =@"off";
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm loading the button in the second view controller:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.text.text=[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"];
```

How can I ensure the `UISwitch` state represents the value in the `NSUserDefaults` (i.e. when it's OFF it shows as OFF and when ON shows as ON)?

Comment: You should not use `setValue:forKey:` under normal circumstances. Use `setObject:forKey:`. But for a `BOOL` value it's easier to use `setBool:forKey:` to set the `BOOL` value and `boolForKey:` to read the `BOOL`. No need for strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[self.valueSwitch setOn:[[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] boolValue] animated:YES];
[self.valueSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(stateSwitched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

In `stateSwitched` do this:

```
-(void)stateSwitched:(id)sender {
    UISwitch *tswitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: tswitch.isOn ? @"YES" : @"NO" forKey:@"truthonoff"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: its giving an error with valueswitch dose this need to be declared in the h file as a switch?

Comment: You should not declare it in .h file.

Comment: it is not giving error at [self.valueSwitch setOn:[[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] boolValue] animated:YES]; and not allowing to load ?

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand what you are saying. Can you post your updated code and what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Oh ok i worked it out sorry. How would i now use this in a different view. Say i wanted to tell if a user has selected the yes or no. IE if uiswitch state = yes then  else do somthing else?

Comment: DIfferent view means different ViewController?

Comment: yes so say for example im doing this in a different view controller how would i check the value?  NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if (defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff" boolValue animated:YES)
    {
        self.text.text=@"on"
        ;    }

Comment: Do this: if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] boolValue]) {
        self.text.text=@"on" ;
    }

Comment: What is the error? I may be wrong. I didn't compile it.

Comment: Im not sure it crashes on this line however if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] boolValue] ) { self.text.text=@"on" ; }

Comment: I this is all the code - (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
   NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] boolValue] ) { self.text.text=@"on" ; }
}

Comment: Try this:     if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"truthonoff"] isEqualToString:@"YES"] ) { self.text.text=@"on" ; }

Comment: sadly not its still crashing

Answer (score 1):

A little too late but Instead of doing like the answer you have accepted:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject: tswitch.isOn ? @"YES" : @"NO" forKey:@"truthonoff"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

the right way would be:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:tswitch.isOn forKey:@"truthonoff"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

This save you from checking the value of the boolean, since `NSUserDefaults` can take `boolean` value.

Also it would be easier to retrieve the boolean:

```
bool truthonoff = [defaults boolForKey:@"truthonoff"];
```

Read up some more on [boolForKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_8)

Answer (score 0):

Connect your your `UISwitch` to an `IBOutlet` in your `ViewController`.
You can (un-)set the switch with:

```
[mySwitch setOn:TRUE animated:TRUE];
```

[Method Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwitch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISwitch/setOn%3aanimated%3a)

Comment: Use `YES` or `NO`, not `TRUE` for `BOOL` values in Objective-C.